# How to modify columns of a dataframe into values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe df1 and df2, where df1 has columns p1,p2 and p3. While dataframe df2 has values assigned for p1, p2 and p3.
I would like to create a new dataframe (newdf1) where values in df1 becomes columns and p1,p2 and p3 are new values based on dataframe df2..

Query for df1 and df2 are

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"user": ["user1", "user2", "user3"], "p1": ["A", "C", "B"],"p2": ["C", "E", "A"],"p3": ["D", "A", "C"],}, index=[0, 1, 2], )
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"N1": ["p1", "p2", "p3"],"N2": ["2", "3", "4"], }, index=[0, 1, 2], )
```

My df1 looks like this
[image]

And df2 look like this

[image]

While my desired newdf1 should look like this

[image]

(yellow highlight is to show transformation of p1 in the new dataframe)

Comment: Your expected output is not matching the corresponding input.

Comment: I think the values in column `B` should be `0, 0, 2`?

Comment: I spent a lot of time studying your two dataframes and their relationship.  The question still does not make sense to me.  Please be more specific about where all the numbers (not just the highlighted ones) in your desired output came from.

Comment: Thanks Shubham, i got confused too..i have update the post again :)

Comment: pakpe your right, i guess i have missed something..i will update the post, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Sorry for my mistake in earlier post in the tables, i have updated my requirement correctly..the idea is each user has three player (either A,B,C,D,or E) and each player based on position p1,p2,p3 has a different weightage..in my earlier post i made a mistake of having duplicate for user3..as each user will have a distinct players..thanks @pakpe , i hope the scenario is clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
m = df1.melt('user')
m['variable'] = m['variable'].map(df2.set_index('N1')['N2'])
m.pivot('user', 'value', 'variable').fillna(0)
```

**Details:**

`melt` the dataframe on `user`

```
print(m)
    user variable value
0  user1       p1     A
1  user2       p1     C
2  user3       p1     B
3  user1       p2     C
4  user2       p2     E
5  user3       p2     A
6  user1       p3     D
7  user2       p3     A
8  user3       p3     B
```

`map` the `variable` column with corresponding values from `df2`:

```
print(m)

    user variable value
0  user1        2     A
1  user2        2     C
2  user3        2     B
3  user1        3     C
4  user2        3     E
5  user3        3     A
6  user1        4     D
7  user2        4     A
8  user3        4     C
```

`pivot` the above melted dataframe to reshape:

```
value  A  B  C  D  E
user                
user1  2  0  3  4  0
user2  4  0  2  0  3
user3  3  2  0  0  0
```

Comment: thanks Shubham, you have cracked it!! brilliant solution actually..though i have not heard crosstab function before...thanks again!!

Comment: @ArunMenon if each users have distinct set of players we can simplify the above answer a little bit by using `pivot` instead of crosstab with `aggfunc`..check the edit.

Answer (score 2):

`stack` so that you can `merge` the second DataFrame to bring over the values and then `pivot` to your desired output.

```
(df1.set_index('user').stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1': 'N1'})
    .merge(df2, how='left')
    .pivot(index='user', columns=0, values='N2')
    .rename_axis(columns=None)
    .fillna(0))
```

---

```
       A  B  C  D  E
user                
user1  2  0  3  4  0
user2  4  0  2  0  3
user3  3  2  4  0  0
```

Comment: i have updated the post...you are right i made an error for user3